# Search in HTML-table - Combine multiple values (dropdown, textfield ..)

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter

Is it possible to add a dropdown-menu to the form, and that the function will combine the selected value from the dropdown and the value of the textfield to search?

The code is applied on a HTML table, so that the visitor can search in the table.

Thanks! :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function search (phrase, _id){
    var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var table = document.getElementById(_id);
    var ele;
    for (var r = 0; r < table.rows.length; r++){
        ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,"");
        var displayStyle = 'none';
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i])>=0)
                displayStyle = '';
            else {
                displayStyle = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;
    }
}

</script>

<form>

<b>Words:</b>

<input name="filter" onkeyup="search(this, 'my-table', 1)" type="text">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After `var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");`
Try this:

```
var dd = document.getElementById("your_dropdown_id");
words.push(dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text);
```

.
.
  UPDATE:

Above shown is the answer to your **original** question. Now you have some different problem.

Your problem is, you are searching a string with capital letters in it (i.e. 'HBO' OR 'MBO') in a string with all the letters in lower case (You have used `ele.toLowerCase()` in your `if` condition.)
Now try this:

```
var displayStyle = 'block';
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i].toLowerCase()) == -1) {
        displayStyle = 'none';
        break;
    }
```

Initialising `displayStyle` to `'block'` and changing it before `break;`, in whole the above shown code, is the best way for this logic.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @Maarten: Please convey if this answer has helped you in any whichever way **OR** there is some problem you are facing, in that case we might be able to help you **OR** please _guide_ us in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm doing something wrong ..

```
function search (phrase, _id){
    var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");

    var dd = document.getElementById("education");
    words.push(dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text);

    var table = document.getElementById(_id);
    var ele;
    for (var r = 0; r < table.rows.length; r++){
        ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,"");
        var displayStyle = 'none';
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i])>=0)
                displayStyle = '';
            else {
                displayStyle = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;
    }
}

</script>

<form>

<b>Words:</b>

<input name="filter" onkeyup="search(this, 'my-table', 1)" type="text"><br>

<b>Education:</b>

<select id="education">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="MBO">MBO</option>
   <option value="HBO">HBO</option>
   <option value="University">University</option>
</select>

</form>
```